# bash terminal and tilix cannot send command to the background

Tags: bash, background-process

Hi I have an issue with the usage of & to send command to background.
I saw that some command like this one doesn't work it display the result and block the terminal.

```bsh
find /<directory> -newermt "-24 hours" -ls &
```

I thought this was because I needed to redirect the STD so I also tried this command

```bsh
find /<directory> -newermt "-24 hours" -ls 0> file.txt &
```

but nothing to do the terminal get blocked anyway.
I also manage to find that tilix isn't able to handle the background process and I don't know why too.
https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/
Do someone know were I can find some documentation about this like a man ?
or just have an answer ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: like a man, or like a man page?  You made me laugh

Comment: You are conflating shell and terminal, and you'll find that neither your shell nor your terminal are "blocked".  This is almost certainly a duplicate, because this is a common misunderstanding that gets asked about again and again.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/174242/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146120/5132 for starters.

Comment: @Stewart no man page ahahhahahhahaha

Comment: @JdeBP yes right I understand now thanks